# Can't get config value from Akka ActorSystem

Tags: akka, akka-http

When I print current config values using `println(system.settings.config.root().values())`
I got long list of values, cutted:

> [SimpleConfigObject({"separator":":"}),
>   SimpleConfigObject({"home":"/usr/local/Cellar/typesafe-activator/1.3.10"}),
>   ,
>   SimpleConfigObject({"country":{"format":"UA"},"dir":"/Users/sr/ScalaProjects/akka-http-test","home":"/Users/sr","language":"en","name":"sr"})]

I want to get value of "dir" key.
I try to do it like this:

```
system.settings.config.getValue("dir")
```

but got exception:

> com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting
>   found for key 'dir'

How to get this key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be missing accessing `user` before accessing `dir`.

```
system.settings.config.getConfig("user").getValue("dir")
```

Note that you are not printing the config keys when printing `root().values()`, therefore you cannot see the "user" key. You should be able to see the full config block by printing (e.g.)

```
println(system.settings.config.root().entrySet())
```

Comment: You are right, but can you tell me why is this so? Where did you find this "user" key?

Comment: You can verify if by checking out the whole printout of `system.settings.config.root().values()` - the `dir` block will be nested in a `user` block

Comment: Actually when I copy all result from printing system.settings.config.root().values() and search in it for word "user" I can't find it at all. But your solution is working, so I will mark you answer as correct. Thanks

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, just noticed you had `values()` as well in your call. this will leave out the first level of keys in your config. If you want to see the full picture try printing `system.settings.config.root().entrySet()`